# Using nested nth-child selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am using `sass` and have the following `html` structure:

```
<div class='d1'>
  <div class='d2'>
    <div class='d3'>
     <div class='d4'>
      <div class='d5'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set different `background-position` of each `div` but removing the class and using nested `sass` instead like this:

```
  & div:nth-child(2)
    background-position: 0px 0px
    div
      transform: translate3d(60px,0,0)
      div
        background-position: -120px 0px
        div
          background-position: -180px 0px
          div
            background-position: -240px 0px
```

It is working but I found it wrong, because on each `div` all `background-position` properties of parent `divs` are applied, too.

I have try to use `nth-child` and `first-child` selectors with combination of `&` in order to restrict `css` inheritance but was not able to build something valid:

```
   & div:nth-child(2)
    background-position: 0px 0px
    & div:first-child
      transform: translate3d(60px,0,0)
      & div:first-child
        background-position: -120px 0px
        & div:first-child
          background-position: -180px 0px
          & div:first-child
            background-position: -240px 0px
```

Could anyone tell how this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried selecting only direct children with `>` ?

Comment: Why would you combine nth-child and nested syntax ? Can you provide a demo or the example code you've found that suggests this should work?

Comment: @JohnTobin Thanks for the hint. Using `>` and `div` only fix the issue.